# Is it possible to have immutable fields in Hibernate/JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, immutability

In our application, we need to have fields that are assignable only once.

At first we thought of encapsulating the fields and making the setters private. However, some questions arouse:

- Without a public setter, is Hibernate still able to map the field from the database?
- Can I strip out the setter and make the field mutable only in the entity constructor?
- Finally, is there any standard JPA way to make a field immutable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- Ad. 1: I believe JPA uses plain private fields for both read and write if annotations are placed on fields and not on getters. Recently I discovered that Hibernate as an underlying JPA provider does not even need `get*()` and `set*()` methods at all. This was truly enlightening solution since from the beginning I thought Hibernate needs accessors. So the answer is: **you don't need setters** as far as Hibernate is concerned.
- Ad. 2: However please note that Hibernate still needs no-arg constructor, otherwise it will fail to load entities with a descriptive exception. This is also a JPA requirement.
- Ad. 3: No, there isn't. Remember that your collections would also had to be immutable.

Comment: so, for field access: `private` fields + Hibernate FIELD-access + no arg constructor (for Hibernate) + arg Constructor (for making immutable object)? is that all, @Tomasz?

Comment: I just want to add that the no-arg constructor can be declared `private`. So if you have a `Point` class with two `final` fields: `x` and `y`, you can have one public constructor `Point(int x,int y)` to be used by client code and a private constructor `Point()` that is used by hibernate. Writing a comment explaining the purpose of the private constructor would be a good idea.

Comment: @W.K.S even better idea is to create custom annotation (for example `@ForHibernate`). There is a chance that your IDE will stop marking that constructor as unused after adding annotation (at least eclipse)

Answer (score 18):

Try

```
@Column(updatable = false)
```

And make your setter private. (Leave your getter public if you want)

I think this is the best practice.

P.S.: JPA uses field access if you annotate your fields and uses getter/setter access if you annotate your getter method.

Comment: Sadly this is true, but trying to update a column will merely ignore the field, leading to horrible bugs if a programmer forgets about that flag and assumes it is writable.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
@Column(updatable = false)
```

From javadoc:

> Whether the column is included in SQL UPDATE statements generated by
>   the persistence provider.

Answer (score 3):

In JPA 2.0 you have two ways to define what attributes should be persisted:

1. Access(FIELD) - the fields name are persisted,
2. Access(PROPERTY) - the properties name are persisted.

If no Access(-) annotation is used, the decision what access will be used depends on where you put your @Id annotation. If you put it next to your field - Access(FIELD) will be used. If you put it next to your accessor - Access(PROPERTY) will be used.

Therefore, if you use Access(FIELD) you don't have to have an appropriate JavaBeans-style accessor for particular field. You can have a private field named 'myField' and a public setter for it named 'public setBlahBlah(-)'. The JPA will persist just the 'myField'.

Answer (score 1):

You can mark an entity with `@Entity(mutable=false)` or `@Immutable` annotations for the framework to make use of this fact for performance gain in caching and such. (Hibernate)

Then you can use an immutable wrapper class like this:

```
public class ImmutableStuff {
    private final FooField barValue;

    public ImmutableStuff(Stuff stuff) {
        barValue = stuff.barValue;
    }

    public FooField getBarValue(){
        return barValue;
    }
}
```