# Spring - Failed to execute CommandLineRunner: @Bean

Tags: java, spring, configuration, frameworks

I 'm new on Spring and getting the follow exception

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-12 21:48:27.204 ERROR 13289 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816) [spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
```

This is my class that runs the application

```
   @SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner init(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return args -> {
            Stream.of("John", "Julie", "Jennifer", "Helen", "Rachel").forEach(name -> {
                User user = new User(name, name.toLowerCase() + "@domain.com");
                userRepository.save(user);
            });
            userRepository.findAll().forEach(System.out::println);
        };
    }
}
```

This is the guide that I'm following: [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-angular-web)

I commented the part regarding `Stream.of`of the method `init` and put in place a `System.out.println("hello");` and it works fine. 
So the problem is `Stream`.

```
      .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-06-12 22:48:13.015  INFO 13817 --- [           main] springboot.angularest.Application        : Starting Application on Marta-Strasse.local with PID 13817 (/Users/Simone/IdeaProjects/angularest/target/classes started by Simone in /Users/Simone/IdeaProjects/angularest)
2019-06-12 22:48:13.021  INFO 13817 --- [           main] springboot.angularest.Application        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-06-12 22:48:15.430  INFO 13817 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2019-06-12 22:48:15.555  INFO 13817 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 114ms. Found 1 repository interfaces.
2019-06-12 22:48:16.100  INFO 13817 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d61747a1] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-06-12 22:48:16.473  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-06-12 22:48:16.518  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-06-12 22:48:16.519  INFO 13817 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
2019-06-12 22:48:16.703  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-06-12 22:48:16.703  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3524 ms
2019-06-12 22:48:16.922  INFO 13817 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2019-06-12 22:48:17.057  INFO 13817 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2019-06-12 22:48:17.131  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2019-06-12 22:48:17.208  INFO 13817 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.10.Final}
2019-06-12 22:48:17.220  INFO 13817 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-06-12 22:48:17.364  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-06-12 22:48:17.507  INFO 13817 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2019-06-12 22:48:17.975  INFO 13817 --- [           main] org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator     : HHH000182: No default (no-argument) constructor for class: springboot.angularest.model.User (class must be instantiated by Interceptor)
2019-06-12 22:48:18.322  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@6451a288'
2019-06-12 22:48:18.326  INFO 13817 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-06-12 22:48:18.982  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-06-12 22:48:19.030  WARN 13817 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-06-12 22:48:19.351  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-06-12 22:48:19.359  INFO 13817 --- [           main] springboot.angularest.Application        : Started Application in 7.321 seconds (JVM running for 9.837)
2019-06-12 22:48:19.474  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-06-12 22:48:19.579  INFO 13817 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-06-12 22:48:19.591 ERROR 13817 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:816) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:797) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:324) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    at springboot.angularest.Application.main(Application.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : springboot.angularest.model.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : springboot.angularest.model.User
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:351) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:253) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:527) ~[spring-orm-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:138) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:61) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy83.findAll(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at springboot.angularest.Application.lambda$init$1(Application.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) ~[spring-boot-2.1.5.RELEASE.jar:2.1.5.RELEASE]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : springboot.angularest.model.User
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:85) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.PojoInstantiator.instantiate(PojoInstantiator.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tuple.entity.AbstractEntityTuplizer.instantiate(AbstractEntityTuplizer.java:673) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.instantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4950) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1682) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.instantiate(SessionImpl.java:1666) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1663) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1561) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:731) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:948) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:340) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2689) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2672) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2506) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2501) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:504) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:395) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:220) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1508) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1537) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1505) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:132) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.3.10.Final.jar:5.3.10.Final]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:313) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:74) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:359) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:200) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:644) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:608) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$invoke$3(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:595) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:59) ~[spring-data-commons-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:295) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

2019-06-12 22:48:19.598  INFO 13817 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-06-12 22:48:19.599  INFO 13817 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-06-12 22:48:19.600  INFO 13817 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2019-06-12 22:48:19.612  INFO 13817 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2019-06-12 22:48:19.621  INFO 13817 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

By debug on Stream.of() I got that:

```
 private void callRunner(CommandLineRunner runner, ApplicationArguments args) {
    try {
        runner.run(args.getSourceArgs());
    } catch (Exception var4) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to execute CommandLineRunner", var4);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help greatly if you provided entire stacktrace, with the error that caused the `IllegalStateException`. Additionally you can run the application in debug mode for more info.

I can only guess that the problem is with the user entity.

Does you `User` look like in the documentation:

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private final String name;
    private final String email;

    public User(String name, String email) {
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
      this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
      return email;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Here is the culprit `Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: No default constructor for entity:  : springboot.angularest.model.User; nested exception is org.hibernate.InstantiationException: No default constructor for entity:  : springboot.angularest.model.User`

Please try a `User` class with default constructor. When creating JPA entities it is essential to think about reflection that will be performed upon it. For this reason it's sometimes required to create getters, setters and constructors even if you never call them.:

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public long id;
    public String name;
    public String email;

    public User() {}

    public User(String name, String email) {
      this.name = name;
      this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Comment: But on the guide they were:  
private long id;
private final String name;
private final String email;

Comment: Yes. I have noticed that too. You can replace `public` fields with `private` if you provide getter and setter for that field. You can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033905/create-the-perfect-jpa-entity for more info about ideal `@Entity` structure.

For `final` modifiers, it's better to add annotation ensuring that field will not be modified in the database either, as well as make setters private. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7944613/5521670)